# List comprehension removing elements from a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am working on a program that replaces the file extension `.hpp` with `.h` using **list comprehension**.

Here is my code:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames

filenames = [x.replace("hpp", "h") for x in filenames if x[-3:] == "hpp"]

print(filenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

Here is my output:

```
['stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
```

Can someone explain why my program is returning only the elements that have been modified and how to fix it?

Comment: Because the `if` in the list comprehension discards elements with an extension different from "hpp"

Comment: It's being caused by the conditional you have at the end of your comprehension `if x[-3:] == "hpp"` is saying that you will insert any item ending in hpp, and then replace `hpp` with `h`. If you just want to replace and leave the other elements alone, strip off that conditional as x.replace("hpp", "h") will do nothing to files not containing `hpp`. Note, this replacement can accidentally rename files that have `hpp` in them somewhere other than the end.

Comment: The only added strings are the one which had an "hpp" in the end right ? Then `x.replace( ... )` only returns a string when a replacement can be done, otherwise, it's ignored. To fix this, maybe try the `endswith()` string method

Comment: In essence, the list comprehension just keeps the elements that match the requirements given by the list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution would be to replace `.hpp` with `.h` (including the dot). This of course only works if you know that `.hpp` will not be in the filename.

Code:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames

filenames = [x.replace(".hpp", ".h") for x in filenames]

print(filenames)
```

Output:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Regarding to why your program does not work: The if excludes the elements that do not end with `.hpp` so they cannot be in the final list. (I think this is very good explained in the comments to your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative indexing parameter to take into account only the last 3 elements of the string (since this is the file extension) as follows:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
filenames = [f'{x[:-3]}{x[-3:].replace("hpp", "h")}' for x in filenames]

print(filenames)
```

**Output:**

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Answer (score 0):

JANO's answer is very good, and I presume it to be okay for the use case. But should you want to manage even the case of a filename like 'myfile.hpp.out' you will need something more complicated, and perhaps a little less efficient:

```
filenames = [(lambda x:x.replace("hpp", "h") if x[-3] == 'hpp' else x)(x) for x in filenames]
```

Comment: I have a question, can you keep 2 file extensions just for 1 file?

Comment: The file extension will always be the part after the final dot, but you can have more than one dot in your filename, both in *nix and Windows

Comment: How does windows know after which dot does the file extension come?

Comment: The last one. Note btw that there is nothing special about file extensions, they are just a very convenient convention which is extensively used by file managers and other programs. The file system, or the operating system, do not care about them. In other words, Windows, or the NTFS, don' really know what a file extension is; Explorer, Word, Excel do